# Search google in chromium from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just recently updated to Android Studio 2.3.3 ,, and i noticed

that there is an option to

```
  Search Google
```

when you highlight some text ,,

when i clicked it it used Mozilla Firefox for the search although Chromium

is my default browser ,, how can i set it to use chromium instead and if

there is no way to  , , can you suggest some plugin to that can deliver 
this functionality for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Setting-->Tools-->Web Browsers and change the setting as required. Change Setting as you need.

[image: Android Studio Web Browser Setting]